# topology general

Tags: general-topology

Let X = {1,2,3} and a function N on X given by N(1) = {{1,2},{1,2,3}}  , N(2) = {{2,3},{1,2,3}}    , N(3) = {{2,3},{1,2,3}}    .

(b) Add a minimal number of neighbourhoods to the above deﬁnition of N to indeed obtain a neighbourhood topology, called ˜N

N(1)={{1,2},{1,3},{1,2,3}, {1}}, 
N(2)={{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3},{2}}, N(3)={ {2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}

Is this right? can someone help me?

Comment: ?? Topology of which space? $X$? $P(X)$? What is *a neighborhood topology*?

Comment: Topology Space on X I think .

Comment: I guess it is topology on $X=\{1,2,3\}$.. what might be the meaning is, try adding minimal number of sets to $N(1)$ to make it a topology.. i.e., you should check if $N(1)$ is already a topology and if not what actually is missing? if you add all elements in $P(X)$ it would obviously be a topology, that is the reason we are looking for a minimal collection to make $N(1)$ a topology on $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and similarly for $N(2),N(3)$...

Comment: You've added way too many sets for it to be minimal. You also don't have the empty set $\emptyset$

Comment: N(1)={{1,2},{1,3},{1,2,3}, {1}}, N(2)={{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3},{2}}, N(3)={{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}, I am lost in this, would this be more correct then?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, presumably its alternative terminology for a *neighbourhood system.*

Comment: This question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to define a topology on a set $X$. One is by specifying for each point $x\in X$ a neighborhood basis $N(x)$. A set $\Omega\subset X$ is *open* if for each $x\in\Omega$ there is an $U\in N(x)$ with $x\in U\subset \Omega$.

In order for a family of subsets ${\cal N}:=\bigl(N(x)\bigr)_{x\in X}$ to constitute a neighborhood basis certain axioms have to fulfilled:

(i) $\quad x\in U$ for all $U\in N(x)$.

(ii) $\quad$ Given any two $U$, $V\in N(x)$ there is a $W\in N(x)$ with $W\subset U\cap V$.

These two axioms are obviously fulfilled by the ${\cal N}$  in  question. But there is a third axiom, which is a kind of "topological triangle inequality":

(iii) $\quad$ For any $U\in N(x)$ there is a $V\in N(x)$ with $V\subset U$ such that $U$ is a neighborhood of all points $y\in V$. This means that for all $y\in V$ there is a $U'\in N(y)$ with $U'\subset U$.

Coming back to the ${\cal N}$ in question: Since  $U:=\{1,2\}$ is a minimal neighborhood of $1$ one would have $V=U$, but $U$ is not a neighborhood of $2\in V$. Therefore axiom (iii) is violated in this instance. Adding $\{1,2\}$ to $N(2)$ fixes the defect.

Answer (score 1):

"Neighbourhood topology" is, in my not so humble opinion a badly chosen name (not that I can come up with a good one, unfortunately). The task is to extend the neighbourhood map $N$ by adding as few new neighbourhoods as possible to obtain a valid neighbourhood system that makes $X$ a neighbourhood space.

Let us recapitulate. In a topological space $S$, for every point $x \in S$, we have the system $\mathscr{V}(x)$ of neighbourhoods of $x$. These systems have the following properties:

1. $(\forall V \in \mathscr{V}(x))(x\in V)$ - every neighbourhood of $x$ contains $x$
2. $(\forall V \in \mathscr{V}(x))(\forall A \subset S)(V \subset A \Rightarrow A \in \mathscr{V}(x))$ - every superset of a neighbourhood is a neighbourhood
3. $(\forall V_1,\dotsc, V_n \in \mathscr{V}(x))\left(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n V_k \in \mathscr{V}(x)\right)$ - finite intersections of neighbourhoods are still neighbourhoods
4. $(\forall V\in \mathscr{V}(x))(\exists W \in \mathscr{V}(x))(\forall y \in W)(V \in \mathscr{V}(y))$ - every neighbourhood of $x$ is also a neighbourhood of all points "sufficiently close" to $x$

Conversely, if one has a family of filters $\mathscr{F}(x)$ on $S$, one for each point, with these properties, then $S$ is a *neighbourhood space*. There is a unique topology $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{F}$ on $S$ such that $\mathscr{F}(x)$ is the neighbourhood filter of $x$ in $\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{F}$. The topology is of course $$\mathscr{T}_\mathscr{F} = \left\lbrace U \subset S : (\forall x \in U)(U \in \mathscr{F}(x)) \right\rbrace.$$

So the task here is to add the minimal number of new sets to the systems to obtain a system $\{N(x) : x\in X\}$ that satisfies conditions 1. to 4.

The given system

$$N(1) = \{\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\} , N(2) = \{\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\} , N(3) = \{\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$

satisfies conditions 1. to 3., but condition 4. is only satisfied for $N(2)$ and $N(3)$, not for $N(1)$, since $\{1,2\}$ is not a neighbourhood of $2$, and $\{1,2\}$ is the smallest neighbourhood (yet) of $1$. There are two options to fix that, one can add $\{1,2\}$ to the system of neighbourhoods of $2$, or one can add a smaller neighbourhood to $N(1)$ (one can also do both, of course). With either choice, one must then check whether further adjustments are necessary, and one must determine which way to fix the defect introduces the fewest new neighbourhoods.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think the correct answer is:

$$\tilde{N}(1) = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$

$$\tilde{N}(2) = \{\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$

$$\tilde{N}(3) = \{\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$$

The idea is that this is the neighbourhood system corresponding to the open topology $$\mathcal{O} = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}.$$

I'm not sure how to actually prove that $\tilde{N}$ is the most efficient solution to the problem, but I think the best way we would be to show that $\mathcal{O}$ is maximally efficient.